# refresh list contents in lwuit

Tags: list, combobox, refresh, lwuit

I am developing an application that provides a `List` of items to user on the basis of choosen category from `ComboBox`. I am implementing this in lwuit. The problem is , when i change the selected item from `ComboBox`, the updated list do not appear on screen. How to refresh the `List` within the screen. and the selected item from `ComboBox` must be maintained when the user comes back to this `Form`.

Answer (score 1):

1)Add an selection listener on the combo box (combox.addselectionlistener(new Sele....))

2)get the selected item and its index on the event of selection changed

3)Assign a new data source to your list based on the selection with :

```
yourList = new List(java.lang.Object[] items);// this can be an array of strings.
```

so if you have 3 items in combo box, you should have 3 different string arrays for each item of the combo box.

4) When the user comes back to the form, set the selected item as :

```
combox.setSelectedIndex(index of that item here)
```